# Wordpress single.php template based on the page you come from

Tags: php, wordpress, tags, conditional-statements

In a Wordpress-based site an user filters the posts based on tags. So, for example, with archive.php I show the filtered posts.

My question is: if, in this page, I click on a post to see the single post, can I show the post in a different way than the default-one?

I would like that - if a I see the single post coming from the page filtered by tag - I can insert in single.php a conditional tag (for example: "if the user comes from a page in wich he filtered the posts by a tag, show me as first image of the post a certain image and not another").

Is it possible with Wordpress API?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think there is a template hierarchy for taxonomy. https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/

Comment: Sure it is @AndrewWelch, but my question is: once my user is on the page generated by the template archive.php or - say - tag-sometag.php and go to the single.php view of a post, how can I enter - in single.php template - a conditional that tells "if the user come here from  archive.php or tag-sometag.php,  do some stuff"?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie with php $_SESSION. Or you can pass a parameter in the URL and retrieve it with $_GET.

Otherwise AFAIK there is no built in Wordpress functionality for this - e.g. to track the path someone on your site and display different templates according to it.

You could make another template that applies to only pages that have come from the ones you specified and do something based on that. E.g. from archive you link to your custom post type pages and they use a specific template.

If "if the user comes from a page in wich he filtered the posts by a tag, show me as first image of the post a certain image and not another"

The you will have  /tag/ in the url so you can provide a different template or check for this, there are probably some conditionals to do something based on taxonomy as I previously mentioned and do an if statement for it.

You might need to put a bit more detail in your question and think it through a little more.

if you just want to make a custom single post template you can create one maybe something like this http://askwpgirl.com/creating-a-custom-single-php-template/

Comment: Thanks Andrew. The solution "to make another template that applies to only pages that have come from the ones you specified" is not viable because I would like that, if a user searched for "tag1", I can pass "tag1" in single.php in a conditional form like "if user comes here having searched for tag1, do some stuff". How about "to pass a parameter in the URL and retrieve it with $_GET."? Maybe with "get_query_var()" function? Thanks for your help!